# HTML and Python - Radio Button Choice then Redirect

Tags: python, html

I want my app when I click the radio button of choice, it will redirect me to the page that I want it to, here's my code:

```
@app.route('/',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'GET': #html radio form
        return render_template('home.html', selected = "home")
```

then my HTML file:

```
<h2>What do you want to do?</h2>

<form method = "GET">

<form class="p2c-form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="p2c-form-group">
                            <label for="show">Show all SKU</label>
                            <input id="show" type="radio">
                        </div>

                        <div class="p2c-form-group">
                            <label for="add">Add an SKU</label>
                            <input id="add" type="radio">
                        </div>

                        <div class="p2c-form-group">
                            <label for="remove">Remove an SKU</label>
                            <input id="remove" type="radio">
                        </div>

                        <div class="p2c-form-group">
                            <label for="insert">Insert an SKU</label>
                            <input id="insert" type="radio">
                        </div>

                        <div class="p2c-form-group">
                            <label for="forecast">Use forecaster</label>
                            <input id="forecast" type="radio" >
                        </div>



                            <button type="submit" class="p2c-button" value = "p2cbtn">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

How do I if-else the value of these buttons so that when the user chooses the radio button then clicks "submit", he would be redirected to the assigned page. Do I if-else within the HTML(using <%%>? or in Python(using request.form['']?  How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.form` in python, without even creating an if-else block

```
def x():
    var = request.form["Radio"]
    return render_template("%s.html" % var, selected="home")
```

Make sure to set the name of radio buttons. If you only want the user to select one of the radio buttons, set them to the same name

```
<input type="radio" name="Radio" val="select">
<input type="radio" name="Radio" val="show">
```

This will ensure that only one of those buttons can be selected

Comment: <div class="p2c-form-group">
                            <label for="remove">Remove an SKU</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="Radio" val="remove">